# IOS AVPlayer won't play video

Tags: ios, video, ios6, avplayer

I'm trying to play a video usingso I got some code from a tutorial but it won't work.

Here's the code I use :

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    avAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
    avPlayerItem =[avPlayerItem initWithAsset:avAsset];
    avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
    avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
    [avPlayerLayer setFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
    [avPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [avPlayer play];

}
```

I don't know what's wrong it doesn't give ny errors it just gives black screen.
Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Thanks s1mon and matt for your help.

Here's the new code it might help someone:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    avAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
    avPlayerItem =[[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset];
    avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
    avPlayerLayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
    [avPlayerLayer setFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
    //[avPlayerLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor redColor]CGColor]];
    [avPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [avPlayer play];

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I have tried to implement same code in my app , i am using Tableview to show all the videos coming from server, i have url for video, when i am passing this on cell, than its not play it, please help...

Comment: Interesting how I set the background color to red just like you did in your commented out code to make sure the layer is visible on screen.

Answer (score 12):

This might not be the actual problem, but this code is certainly wrong:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]
```

First of all, try not to start with a file path; start with a file URL. That way, there is no conversion needed. But if you *must* perform a conversion from a file path to a URL, use `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:`. A file URL is a special kind of animal and you must ask for one specifically when you are converting from a path.

Comment: Apparently that was the problem :D
Thankssssssssss :D

Comment: This is ridiculous. Both `URLWithString` and `fileURLWithPath:` create a valid `NSURL` instance. Why the former does not work with `AVPlayer` makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot to create an instance of `AVPlayerItem` in this line:

```
avPlayerItem =[avPlayerItem initWithAsset:avAsset];
```

This just sends `initWithAsset:` to `avPlayerItem` (which is probably nil when this method is called). Try changing it to instantiate an new `AVPlayerItem` which you can then assign to `avPlayerItem`, like this:

```
avPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:avAsset];
```

Comment: This also was a problem :D
Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a `swift 2.0 version`, here is what worked for me. Cheers.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit

class VideoViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.setupVideoPlayerView()
    }
    private func setupVideoPlayerView()
    {
        let path = "HTTP_VIDEO_URL_HERE"
        let nsURL = NSURL(string: path)
        let avAsset = AVAsset(URL: nsURL!)
        let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)

        let avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)
        let avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(layer: avPlayer)

        avPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)

        self.player = avPlayer

        self.player!.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
        self.player!.play()

    }

}
```